# Scroll DIV by scrolling another and the way around

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two DIVs next to each other. If I scroll the first, the second should scroll too. This is working with this JS Code:

```
$('#firstDiv').on('scroll', function () {        
    $('#secondDiv').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());       
});
```

If I want to apply this to the second DIV too, so that the first DIV scrolls by scrolling the second, I tried it this way:

```
$('#firstDiv').on('scroll', function () {        
    $('#secondDiv').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());       
});

$('#secondDiv').on('scroll', function () {
    $('#firstDiv').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
});
```

The problem now is, that both are scrolling super slow. Like so slow, that it nearly is not visible.
I guess they start to interact with each other or block each other.

How to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

They definitively slow down, particularly while scrolling with mouse wheel.
I think it's either use a timeout variable so there's not so many events fired when you're scrolling, or use some javascript code to keep them sync'd directly, like this small <1kb plugin does:
http://asvd.github.io/syncscroll/

Comment: This looks exactly like how I want to have it :) I will try to install it ...